# Портирование html сервиса

Tags: java, android

Приложение при старте открывает веб форму из ресурсов, а в ресурсе уже захардкожен *html-скрипт*, который должен делать расчёт по формуле - переношу этот сервис на андроид - http://bast.ru/support/voltage-drop.html

Но возникает проблема :

если я открываю приложение через браузер онлайн на телефоне - кнопка *Расчёт* - работает ,

если я копирую *html-код* в девайс, то кнопка *Расчёт* не работает, кнопка *Очистить* - работает.

Есть предположение: может быть функция расчёта обращается к классу, который находится за пределами этой страницы? Если да, то где он находится?

**Вот сам код странички внутри проекта андройд -**

```
<h1>Расчет падения напряжения в двухпроводной линии</h1>

</div>


<p class="alert alert-success">Форма позволяет рассчитать падение напряжения в однофазной двухпроводной линии переменного или постоянного тока, при использовании <strong>медного</strong> кабеля.</p>
<script>
function napr (obj)
{
if(obj.DLN.value==0 || obj.TOP.value==0 || obj.KPL.value==0)
{
obj.res1.value=""
obj.res2.value=""
}
else
{
var d = obj.PPS.value 

var L3 = obj.DLN.value
var L2 = L3.toString()
var L1 = L2.replace(',','.')
var L 


var I3 = obj.TOP.value
var I2 = I3.toString()
var I1 = I2.replace(',','.')
var I 

var n3 = obj.KPL.value 
var n2 = n3.toString()
var n1 = n2.replace(',','.')
var n 

var U = obj.NIP.value

d=Number(d)
L=Number(L1)
I=Number(I1)
n=Number(n1)
U=Number(U)

var R = 0.0175*2*L/d

var uPr = R*I/1000*n
var u = Math.round(uPr*100)/100

var kPr = U-uPr
var k = Math.round(kPr*100)/100

var xPr = uPr/U*100
var x = Math.round(xPr*100)/100

if(isNaN(k)==true || isNaN(u)==true || isNaN(x)==true)
{
obj.res1.value=""
obj.res2.value=""
}
else
{
obj.res1.value=k+" В"
obj.res2.value=u+" В ("+x+"%)"
}

}

} 

</script>
<form name="form1">
<input type ="text" name="DLN" size=10> <strong>L</strong>, длина кабеля, м.<br><br>
<select name="PPS">
<option value="0.5">0.5</option>
<option value="0.75">0.75</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1.5">1.5</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="2.5">2.5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select> <strong>d</strong>, площадь поперечного сечения жилы, мм&sup2.<br><br>
<input type ="text" name="TOP" size=10> <strong>I</strong>, ток одного потребителя, мА. <br><br>
<input type ="text" name="KPL" size=10> <strong>n</strong>, количество потребителей в линии, шт. <br><br>
<select name="NIP">
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
<option value="48">48</option>
<option value="60">60</option>
</select> <strong>U</strong>, напряжение источника питания, В.<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Расчёт" onClick="napr(form1)"><br><br>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="res1" size=15> Величина напряжения на конце линии.<br><br>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="res2" size=15> Абсолютная величина падения напряжения.<br><br>
<input type="reset" value=Очистить><br><br>
</form>

<div class="clearfloat"></div>
</div>
<!--+++++++++++++ Wrapper +++++++++++++++-->
```

**Вот майн активити -**

```
package com.example.kostukovp.calculationofvoltagedrop;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
// actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
// actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.abc_action_menu_item_layout);
// actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));
// getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
// actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));

// actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

// actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
// ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled();


setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

Intent intent = getIntent();
//получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
// String resName = "n" + intent.getIntExtra("head", 0);
// Log.i("name", resName);
Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

//читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier("n0", "raw", "com.example.kostukovp.calculationofvoltagedrop"));

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);

}


//читаем текст из raw-ресурсов
public static String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
{
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
String line;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

try {
while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
builder.append(line);
builder.append("\n ");
}
} catch (IOException e) {
return null;
}
return builder.toString();


}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home:
// app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.

Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

//читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier("n0", "raw", "com.example.kostukovp.calculationofvoltagedrop"));

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);
// this.finish();
return true;
default:
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

//читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier("n0", "raw", "com.example.kostukovp.calculationofvoltagedrop"));

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "en_US", null);
return;
}
}
```

В чём может быть проблема? почему онлайн - работает, а оффлайн - нет?

Comment: Код тяжело читается, воспользуйтесь тегами. Расчеты, вроде, несложные. Не проще перенести их на андроидовские виджеты, без использования расчетов в webview?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.